# Join a table in SQL based off two columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

```
 Employees (columns: ID, Name)
```

and

```
 employee partners (EmployeeID1, EmployeeID2, Time)
```

I want to output EmployeName1, EmployeeName2, Time instead of imployee ids.

(In other words, replace the ids with names, but in two columns at a time)

How would I do this?  Would JOIN be the appropriate command?

Comment: Yes. `JOIN` is the right command. Read about it a bit and try a query. If you can't get it to work, post the query you tried to use in your question and we can help from there

Answer (score 1):

you need to join the employee table 2 times as the employee partners table acts as many to many connection.
The select should be:

```
SELECT emp1.name, emp2.name, em.time
FROM Employees emp1 
JOIN employee_partners em ON emp1.id = EmployeeID1
JOIN Employees emp2 on emp2.id = EmployeeID2
```

Comment: IS better if you use employee_partners  as main tale and the two Employees  as  joined .. (for me)

Comment: Agree from readability point. Since it's a regular join it has no impact on the logic.

Comment: You need an outer join for such a relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Often in these situations, you want to use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT e1.name as name1, e2.name as name2, em.time
FROM employee_partners ep LEFT JOIN
     Employees e1
     ON e1.id = ep.EmployeeID1 LEFT JOIN
     Employees e2 
     ON e2.id = ep.EmployeeID2;
```

Notes:

- The `LEFT JOIN`s ensure that you do not lose rows if either of the employee columns is `NULL`.
- Use tables aliases; they make the query easier to write and to read.
- Qualify all columns names; that is, include the table name so you know where the column is coming from.
- I also added column aliases so you can distinguish between the names.